# How to cut TextBox width to prevent out of the Grid?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have the next layout

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Width="60" Height="60" />

  <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="Title should be long" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
    <Ellipse Fill="White" Stroke="White" Width="7" Height="7" />
  </StackPanel>

  <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="Message" /> 
  <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Text="Info" />
</Grid>
```

I have an issue in the StackPanel which hosts a Title and Ellipse, the goal is the Online marker by the ellipse whitch should be placed at the end off the title. But it shouldn't out of a view part.

I have tried to put TextBox and Ellipse into cells of the Grid unfortunatly it doesn't help.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
  <Grid.ColumnsDefinitions>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
     <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  </Grid.ColumnsDefinitions>

  <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Title should be long" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
  <Ellipse Grid.Column="1" Fill="White" Stroke="White" Width="7" Height="7" />

</Grid>
```

In my mind it should render correct, but the ellipse is out of view port again.

This is a Expression Blend layout scrinshots, the same layout is rendering in runtime.

The Grid bounds:

[image]

The TextBox bounds:

[image]

The Ellipse bounds:

[image]

So the TextBox and Ellipse is out of the grid :(

Update: I need the next behaviour of layout

1) Short title, the ellipse attached to the title end

[image]

2) Long title, the ellipse attached to the right side of container

[image]

Comment: I don't quite get you requirements. The Ellipse is always in the Grid because it stretches to accomodate it, if anything the Grid is cut.

Comment: The Grid should not be bigger when a page size until it has HorisontalAlignment="Stretch", but it doesn't. No matter is the grid width fixed or not.

Comment: It stetches by default. Anyway, if there is not enough space the contents may be cut or overflow.

Comment: Regarding the newly added screenshots, they are not all that useful. All i care about is run-time, i do not trust any gui-designer, what may seem like a problem here probably isn't one.

Comment: I'm not a designer, be sure I had the same problem at runtime

Comment: When i said gui-designer i mean the tool. Anyway, runtime screenshots are the only trustworthy thing, and i still do not know what it to do instead...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and it renders fine (in other terms it renders in the viewport. See red arrow). Please find attached a screenshot of the results. (I added the showgridlines just to illustrates the rows and cols)

[image]

//--- Changed testing and fixed code for intended effect ---//

*Code changes in XAML: Swapped the width values for the columndefinitions. Added Textwrapping to textblock in order to see entire text. (You could opt for texttrimming instead depending on your aesthetics.)*

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Title should be really really really really really long" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    <Ellipse Grid.Column="1" Fill="White" Stroke="White" Width="7" Height="7"/>
</Grid>
```

*Outcome:*

[image]

Comment: Please add more words into Title

Comment: I added more text and made a correction to you code. See that and the effect appended to my answer above.

Comment: Word wrapping is not allowed :(

Comment: So this solution is working, if the MaxHeight property of the title specified. But there is an issue here, when a title is a short the ellipse stay at the right side of grid and isn't attached to title.

Comment: @ViacheslavSmityukh `HorizontalAlignment="Left"` on the inner grid should fix that. (It defaults to `"Stretch"`.)

Comment: @ViacheslavSmityukh I don't understand the problem with the solution. The ellipse is in the viewport right? Can you elaborate on your issue? For example, draw how you want the view to look like.

Comment: @Markus Jarderot Thanks the left alignment fix it!